# Sort UITableView into sections by date from Array of events

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsarray

I've retrieved data from 2 different shared Google Calendars, and stored the data in an array. I need to sort the data into a sectioned UITableView, sorted by date.

Heres my code:

CalendarModel.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "Time.h"

@interface CalendarModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<Time>* time;

@end
```

CalendarModel.m

```
#import "CalendarModel.h"

@implementation CalendarModel


+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper
{
    return [[JSONKeyMapper alloc] initWithDictionary:@{
            @"gd$when": @"time",
            @"title.$t": @"title",
            }];
}

@end
```

Time.h

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol Time @end

@interface Time : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* startTime;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* endTime;

@end
```

Time.m does nothing, as it's handled by JSONModel

SportsViewController.m

```
#import "SportsViewController.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "CalendarModel.h"
#import "Time.h"
#import "JSONValueTransformer.h"

@interface SportsViewController () 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *events;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *music;

- (NSDate *)dateAtBeginningOfDayForDate:(NSDate *)inputDate;
- (NSDate *)dateByAddingYears:(NSInteger)numberOfYears toDate:(NSDate *)inputDate;

@end

@implementation SportsViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //make HTTP call
    NSString* searchCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/kao1d80fd2u5kh7268caop11o4%%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json"];
    NSString* searchCall2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/3qag5m8iad46mtvsnnqbtrcjjg%%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json"];

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString: searchCall
                                  completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {

                                      //got JSON back
                                      NSLog(@"Got Sports JSON from web: %@", json);

                                      if (err) {
                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                      message:[err localizedDescription]
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                                          return;
                                      }

                                      //initialize the models
                                      _events = [CalendarModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:
                                                json[@"feed"][@"entry"]
                                                ];

                                      if (_events) NSLog(@"Loaded successfully sports models");

                                      //show the Events
                                      [_events addObjectsFromArray:_music];
                                      NSLog(@"%@", _events);
                                      [self.tableView reloadData];

                                  }];

    [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString: searchCall2
                                  completion:^(NSDictionary *json2, JSONModelError *err2) {

                                      //got JSON back
                                      NSLog(@"Got Music JSON from web: %@", json2);

                                      if (err2) {
                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                      message:[err2 localizedDescription]
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                                            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                                          return;
                                      }

                                      //initialize the models
                                      _music = [CalendarModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:
                                                json2[@"feed"][@"entry"]
                                                ];

                                      if (_music) NSLog(@"Loaded successfully music models");
                                      [_events addObjectsFromArray:_music];
                                      //show the Events
                                      [self.tableView reloadData];

                                  }];
    //[events addObjectsFromArray:music];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    }



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - table methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _events.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CalendarModel* event = _events[indexPath.row];


    NSString *dato = [[event.time objectAtIndex:0] startTime];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz";
    NSDate *gmtDate = [formatter dateFromString: dato];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    dato = [formatter stringFromDate:gmtDate];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SportCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           event.title
                           ];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dato;

    return cell;
}
@end
```

So basically all the data i need sorted resides in the _events array. I just do not get how i sort it by date into sections. The reason why startTime and endTime are NSStrings is that, that's what i am returned by the call to the shared calendar on Google

Comment: You mean group into sections and sort by time? Is each section = 1 day? Or you just want to list all the events sorted chronologically?

Comment: Each section would be a day, where an event is present. There are days with no events, days with 1 event or days with multiple events. I'd like the section header to be a date where 1 or more events was retrieved from the calendar. That way the section header would be the date (Time.startTime) (27/3-2013), the cell.textLabel.text would be the CalendarModel.Title, and the cell.detailTextLabel.text would be Time.startTime (converted to only use the actual time of day, the event starts)

Answer (score 13):

First group all your events - you'll have to take care of variable scoping (I'm using days and groupedEvents locally but you'll have to declare those as ivars/properties)

```
    NSMutableArray *days = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableDictionary *groupedEvents = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

- (void)groupEventsIntoDays
{
    for (CalendarModel *event in _events)
    {
        NSString *dato = [[event.time objectAtIndex:0] startTime];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz";
        NSDate *gmtDate = [formatter dateFromString: dato];

        if (![days containsObject:gmtDate])
        {
            [days addObject:gmtDate];
            [groupedEvents setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:event] forKey:gmtDate];
        }
        else
        {
            [((NSMutableArray*)[groupedEvents objectForKey:gmtDate]) addObject:event];
        }
    }

    days = [[days sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] mutableCopy];
}
```

Section headers:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:header.bounds];
    [header addSubview:headerLabel];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:[days objectAtIndex:section]];

    [headerLabel setText:dateAsString];

    return header;
}
```

I only touched the first two lines in your cellForRow - you can modify the rest as needed for display/formatting:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSDate *date = [days objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    CalendarModel *event = [((NSMutableArray*)[groupedEvents objectForKey:date]) objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *dato = [[event.time objectAtIndex:0] startTime];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz";
    NSDate *gmtDate = [formatter dateFromString: dato];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    dato = [formatter stringFromDate:gmtDate];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SportCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                           event.title
                           ];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = dato;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You can also sort using NSSort Descriptors.!

Comment: Made the days and groupedEvents as properties.
I'm getting to errors:
On the line: _days = [_days sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; 
It says "Incompatible pointer types assigning NSMutableArray *_strong from NSArray"

And on viewForHeaderInSection method it expects a return type i guess. It says Control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: My bad. Added mutableCopy to days which should take care of the warning, and added the return for the header view.

Comment: I get null values back. Added an NSLog to print _days, and nothing is in there. Is it the line "for (CalendarModel *event in _events)" that's troubling me? I wanted to use something like "for (Object *event in _events). Array output looks like this: (
    "<CalendarModel> \n   [title]: Everton v Stoke\n   [time]: (\n       \"<Time> \\n   [startTime]: 2013-03-30T18:30:00.000+01:...\n</CalendarModel>",

Comment: You said you made days a property- did you init it, either with [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] or [NSMutableArray array]?

Comment: in - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style

i have 
 _days = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _groupedEvents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

Comment: Can you set breakpoints where you init the array/dictionary, and where you're trying to insert objects, to make sure that the array/dictionary are init'ed when you're trying to use them?  Also put breakpoints at the point where objects are inserted into _days and see  if the if/else statements are getting evaluated properly.  You can also try adding a string into the array and getting it out right away to see if that's working.

Comment: 2013-03-27 14:17:46.086 The Irish House[24853:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'


_days NSMutableArray * 0x0905db90@0 objects

Comment: You're getting that error when trying to get an object out of it? Try init'ing the array right before you add an object to it. Usually the only reason you wouldn't be able to add the object is if the array is still nil.  Did you confirm that your init code is getting called before anything is being added to the array?

Comment: The array has been init'ed. The problem is that it's empty, when the line NSString *dateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:[_days objectAtIndex:section]]; is run in the -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Can you confirm that `groupEventsIntoDays` has run and that at the end of that code, the array is not empty?

Comment: You have no idea how much I was looking for this! You sir are amazing !