# UITableView Grouping By Today, Yesterday, Earlier

Tags: ios, uitableview, grouping

I have a UITableView which displays a Visit entity sorted by date descending.  The cells in this UITableView are custom cells and so far this sorting and display works fine.

But I would like to group the cells by the following headings:

TODAY
YESTERDAY
EARLIER THIS WEEK

I also want to display a custom background graphic as the floating section header title for each section but the grouping is the most important part of this that I would like to get working. I can't find a clear example on how to group by the above or similar "day" headings.

Does anybody have an example of grouping like the above?

Comment: Just calculate the description of how long ago it was and set it as the 'sectionIdentifier' in your data set, then have a section in your table for each identifier. You'll need to tell us more about your data structure if you want more detail than that.

Comment: something like this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657211/sort-uitableview-into-sections-by-date-from-array-of-events